# question about output data as CSV file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, file

I am trying to output the data in the "for loop" as a .csv file. I have looked up some example, but I don't really understand how to implement it within my code block. Can anyone please give me some hints or some code examples? Thank you!

```
public class ItemID extends getRandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int I_IM_ID; //from 1 - 10,000
        double I_PRICE; //from 1.00 - 100.00 
        String I_NAME, I_DATA; //I_NAME = random string 14-24; I_DATA = astring 26-50
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            I_IM_ID = getRandomInteger(1,10000);//
            I_PRICE = getRandomDouble(1,100);
            I_NAME = getAlphaNumericString(28);
            I_DATA = getAlphaNumericString(28);
            System.out.println(I_IM_ID +","+ I_NAME +","+ I_PRICE +","+I_DATA );
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

My sample output:

```
1513,18eDDM8xLQaKMk8liHguUb9zSsQZ,64.29,96qCAzOY2htGDMeCsIGrVSbkS7yY
3973,8jKWUOz1ozMgBQS9XhBIftH2O8FV,76.3,t5JCQRWKiRNuGQqtJqHa3WuXWd4T
9861,KPgPe1feNS8kfgHDjWrfKY911Efr,91.7,AzQDyoHh5MWVp1jFk8vlC7v88Y6i
2295,GJgVD0TW5vpC6rZAP3HWboTvbUFq,55.91,nsURqmxfKyt6IFyZc2QrBsYlQOHu
9829,heSLInqF644xJVgat2OrMYFa6Od7,2.75,zetFM3SYPmGopl4NPRLpNKH4Naya
9874,ezb795OAfF8tCD0RD33iBtMogdRe,67.43,TffJZrQaGS461zgR3BrK4moaTbFi
5241,aelZ8KSN6XluNo1lY131gyuXdR2s,83.04,jGFUl8L6BM3fKvobqKUDxThBgaha
712,yP3WTnfYtaMe5eWISJGfo1uduI4q,17.06,TR0V9gK42HHj5pdGSlKOZhErNNM9
2597,UxXNXd4c7ivJH6fRNuP1I9qFl3Cp,11.57,P6cTB5yuMIFUpaJANvQGS1ilTi8H
1270,GF9QPrSaHf8GbXaAeHDenPJFenYi,41.74,gVapkH3PqOVHgooyZ6nm16WUCT7x
```

Comment: Use a third party csvwriter jar

Answer (score 0):

You should opt for third party libraries, anyways here is explanation of the code.
Following three lines are variable declarations nothing more.

```
    int I_IM_ID;
    double I_PRICE; 
    String I_NAME, I_DATA;
```

The following for loop iterates 10 times, there are 3 methods ( you probably did not copy)

```
  I_IM_ID = getRandomInteger(1,10000);
        I_PRICE = getRandomDouble(1,100);
        I_NAME = getAlphaNumericString(28);
```

getRandomInteger() & getRandomDouble() - takes 2 arguments - first from and second to range
getAlphaNumericString() - takes 1 argument - length to generate random combination of alphabets and numeric

the generated ops are assigned to local variable created and is printed in comma separated format , you have to send this (I_IM_ID +","+ I_NAME +","+ I_PRICE +","+I_DATA ) to a file a for that you need to create op stream with output file